# Duration not appearing for after Video

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

I have recorded live video from the camera using `AVCaptureVideoDataOuput` and `AVAssetWriter` but the resulting video has no duration. Can anyone give a brief idea or a point in the general direction to get the duration working?

Comment: Are you setting [AVAssetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime] to the first sample buffer's PTS? Are you calling [AVAssetWriter finishWriting]? You should show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What needs to be done is define an initial `CMTime`.

```
self.time = CMMakeTime( 0, 30 /* some frame time */ );
```

then

```
[instanceAVAssetWriter setSessionAtSourceTime:self.time];
```

on `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`

```
CMSampleBufferRef sb;
CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTimingInfo;

sampleTimingInfo.duration = CMTimeMake(1,30);
sampleTimingInfo.presentationTimeStamp = self.time;
sampleTimingInfo.decodeTimeStamp = kCMTimeInvalid;

CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, 1, &sampleTimingInfo, &sb);
```

and the end

```
CFRelease( sb );
self.time.value += 1;
```

Comment: Can't even describe the frustration this answer brought an end to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do which is similar to NebulaFox's answer. This code is in the callback for the capturing of video data. The writer has already been initialized and setup.

```
switch (writer.status) {
        case AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown:

            startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sample);

            [writer startWriting];
            [writer startSessionAtSourceTime:startTime];

            if (writer.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting) {
                break ;
            }  
....
```